# Regex changing the param in nodejs express route?! How is that possible and how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

In my Node.js Express I use the bellow regex.

```
router.get('/test/:name(\\w{1,10}([\-]{1}\\w{0,15}){0,5})', (req, res) => {
    console.log(c.green, 'It works!');
    res.send('name is:' + req.params.name);
});
```

Correct formats are:

1. word1   (maximum 15 chars)
2. word1-word2
3. word1-word2[-word3]... (up to 5, maximum 15 chars each, with mandatory '-' between)
4. word_with_underscore-some_other_word-.... (idem)

The filter works, but... the result is altered. How is that even possible?!
Results are : 1 & 2 - correct,
For 3 is: '2-word3'. It alters the param!
Any other param I test, I just get the last char from previous word + '-' + the last word.

I avoided using '*' since it's known for Nodejs to have an current issue with it which will be fixed in next major version. I used it for test, it works well, I can see the param as it is sent, but it also allows all characters that I want to forbid like: {}?":', etc.

Q1: how come regex alters my param?!?!
Q2: how should I do this right? In node.js, I tested several versions on regex101.com and they work fine there but not in node.js

Comment: Express generates a regex based on the route you specified. You might want to check the generated regex [here](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) to see what's the problem. In case you can't make express to generate the right regex, you can also provide your own regex as the first argument and extract the params manually in the handler.

Comment: Just tested and the result is the same as in my page. I modify the Route regex to this: /test/:name([a-z_]{0,}([\-]{0,}[a-z_]{0,15}){0,})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^\w{1,15}(?:-\w{1,15}){0,4}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bIoEl/1/)

Edit:
It seems to be a bug in the regex parser for Express. It looks like it treats the first closing parenthesis as the end of the value for key (for e.g. kitty)

Work around:
Use regex: `/test/((\w+)(-\w+)?(-\w+)?(-\w+)?(-\w+)?)`
and in the code, combine the value of captured groups 0 thru 4

Comment: tested in https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ , same result: last letter from the previous word + "-" + last word. :(

Comment: where do u see the result in that link?

Comment: paste on "route": `/test/:kitty(\w{1,15}(?:-\w{1,15}){0,4}$)`  
type on "path:" `/test/why-is-not-working` and see on right-bottom "**kitty**
    t-working"

Comment: The workaround is doing the job. Good idea.
Maybe we should highlight this bug to node.js foundation? Since you discover it, I just stumble upon it, you should have the honor.

Comment: I was happy too soon. For some reasons, in my code, I can't catch the keys as in the test/demo. When I console.log the res.params I got: `{ '0': '-word3', name: '2-word3' }`. The input text was: _/test/word1-word_2-word3_
Any idea how to get the full param?